# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fab52544020

Tags: swift, button, collections, action, outlet

i have 10 buttons connected as  collection@IBoutlets

and i connect each of them in @Iaction  but it gives me an error when i tap them

```
'unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fab52544020'
```

Comment: Please show us the code of the `@IBAction` that's producing this error. It would also help if you posted a picture of your Connections inspector so we can see how things are set up.

Comment: I mean the actual code that shows the `@IBAction`s and `@IBOutlet`s like in the answer below. Also, I'll guess that the problem is most likely with the connections you've made so if you can show us the Connections inspector that would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

One button must not be linked with more than 1 action. Check it on this tab:
[image: button's actions]

Comment: how to connect multiple buttons to one action

Comment: i did it and connect them in one action

Answer (score 1):

Make two actions connected to the each button, and call the method that you want to call from both actions like:

```
@IBAction func firstBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.methodYouWantToCallInBothCase()
}


@IBAction func secondBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.methodYouWantToCallInBothCase()
}

func methodYouWantToCallInBothCase(){
    codes
}
```

Comment: i did it but thats for this